# array.some is not a function in My Laravel Vue Js Project

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I Practicing laravel & Vue js project. Here i have a wishlist button.

```
<button 
:class="wishlists.some(wishlist => wishlist.product_id === productId) ? activeClass:deactiveClass" 
v-html="wishlists.some(wishlist => wishlist.product_id === productId) ? activeText:deactiveText"
@click="wishlistStatus(productId)" >
</button>
```

This is working perfectly but this is throwing also 2 errors.

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.wishlists.some is not a function
and
TypeError: _vm.wishlists.some is not a function.

Now How I fix this

Comment: What does wishlists look like in Vue dev tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the 'some' method, your 'wishlists' variable must be an array.

If at the time your component initializes, that variable is not yet an array, then your application is going to crash.

This usually happens when you initialize your variable, for example, to null and then make a call to the server to fetch the data.

```
data() {
  whislists: null,
  ...
}
```

There are several ways to fix this:

1. The simplest is to initialize your variable as an array.

```
data() {
  whislists: [],
  ...
}
```

2. Another way to solve it would be to wait for your variable to become an array and then render your button, You can achieve this using a v-if.

```
<button
  v-if="wishlists && wishlists.length"
  :class="wishlists.some(wishlist => wishlist.product_id === productId) ? 
  activeClass:deactiveClass" 
  v-html="wishlists.some(wishlist => wishlist.product_id === productId) ? 
  activeText:deactiveText"
  @click="wishlistStatus(productId)" >
</button>
```

This may be just one of the reasons why your problem occurs.

Other reasons could be:

You are assigning to your variable 'wishlists' data that is not an array without realizing it.

Comment: Before my wishlist was an object like wishlists:{}, now i make this wishlist is an array like wishlists:[]. Now its work perfectly. thanks